# How to compare IP and a URL and see if they go to the same website

Tags: php

How can I see in PHP if the IP and a URL are going to the same website?

I have used Curl to get content of the website, and compared with each other to see if the website is the same. If it isn't the same it would say false. This didn't work!

Comment: Have you tried a ping?

Comment: Are you getting the website contents once by IP address and once by URL and comparing? Note that on a shared host, the IP and URL probably won't go to the same website.

Comment: Can you please clarify what your *goal* is? Because what you want is too ambiguous for a good answer.

Comment: @Darien It's pretty self explanatory...

Comment: If i use URL in browser i wil go to that website but if i use an IP sometimes i get a page like apachi funtion is running normaly. i want to test if i can get to the same website with ip if i dont get to the same website it wil output false else true

Comment: Presumably you are currently doing a simple string comparison of the results and they are not equal when essentially you are seeing the same page? There could be subtle differences in the page generation since you are accessing the page via different "URLs". If you look at the source of the page can you identify the differences?

Comment: @Oktay In that case you might have a look at gethostbyaddr() and then compare the resulting Hostname with your URL. But note that the same website can still be served by the host addressed by the IP due to virtual hosting as the others pointed out. In fact it is very likely that in most cases the IP adress will not return the same website. Even a reverse IP lookup might not yield reliable results, but it may be worth havin a look at that.

Comment: @bouscher can't we just like take something of the website and compare it if it matches then we are on the same website if not then false? I used curl but that didn't work.

Comment: @Oktay Well, yes (parse the site and compare the <TITLE>-tag or something), BUT even if it goes wrong the IP-address might still be the correct IP for the website.

Comment: @Stanyer It's not clear because the condition "is same website" is inherently fuzzy. He says that *exact data equality* is his litmus test, but there are many cases where you can visit the "same website" according to a human yet get different data going over the wire. In addition, a host may have ten sites, and the IP address *coincidentally* takes you to just one of them by default, but how is the software supposed to understand that it is a spurious match?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `gethostbyname` for this.

For example

```
$ip = "1.2.3.4";
$domain = "www.example.com";

if(gethostbyname($domain) == $ip) { echo 'IP/URL Match.'; }
```

[gethostbyname()](https://www.php.net/gethostbyname)

**Edit:**

Quentin pointed out that this doesn't mean they will go to the correct website which is correct. I misread the start of the post. They will only go to the correct website if the default virtual host for the IP address is pointing to the same document root as the URL.

**Edit 2:**

Now that I think about it, due to the problem highlighed in first edit, the only real way I can think of to find this is to match the content, similiar to how you've done.

There are still flaws with this however, say if the website outputted `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` - the content would differ between the two.

Comment: That doesn't mean they'll go to the same website though. Most websites use virtual name hosting to run multiple websites, with different host names, off the same IP address.

Comment: @Quentin - Virtual name hosting is irrelevant, this will still do what the OP asked. Edit: I see now, misread the start of the question.

Comment: Won't you have the same problem if you check the _content_? At least by checking `gethostbyname()` you will get a match - but it could be a many to 1. (?) - Although maybe that is what the OP wants.

Comment: @w3d - if the website resolves to `1.2.3.4`, it doesn't mean that `1.2.3.4` when entered in the address bar will resolve to the same website. If it doesn't have a virtual host, it might point to the doc. root which could be the Apache Test Page. So although `gethostbyname` will return the same IP, they are not always going to be the same website.

Comment: It's like if you have two websites on the same server, `www.1.com` and `www.2.com` - `gethostbyname` will return the same IP Address for both, but they are not the same website.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you try is this:

A VPS can have multiple users, user1, user2 and user3. If you fil in the IP from this VPS in your browser, you will get: Apache is function normaly.

But the owner of the VPS can also say that the IP from the vps will redirect you to user1 on the vps. Now you won't get the message: Apache is function normaly, but you will get a website.

You wnat to check of that happens?

Comment: Yes that is what i mean. if i can reach the website with the ip and the url that is then true but if i get apache is function normly that would be false because its not the same website.